# Creating UI in Android Studio and using it in Unity makes elements jump to 0,0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I made an Activity in Android Studio and added a button in there, added the constraints so the error would go away. When I run an App from Android Studio to my phone, it works fine. When I use an AAR file in Unity and call the activity from there, the buttons jump back to 0,0 like the error said if I did not add constraints, which I did. I'm not getting any errors either as to why it's not able to constraint the button.

Here is how I made the button in my activity.

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="431dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="@string/StringName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I've never really worked with Android Studio UI until now, so I might have forgotten something important here, just hoping one of you guys knows what could be the problem, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The problem is with "app:", everywhere you use it should be replaced with "android:". However android:layout_constraintBottom_toEndOf="parent" doesn't work. Instead you have to use: android:layout_alignParentEnd="true". Also replace "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" with "RelativeLayout".

Unity doesn't work with "app:" for some reason so replacing with "android:" is always necessary. Thanks Soon Santos for telling me about RelativeLayout, I looked at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html and remembered I had gotten an app: problem before and fixed by changing to android:.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Company.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/StringName"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can actually leave out android:layout_alignParentEnd/Start. With RelativeLayout it seems to not jump back to 0,0 at all, so basically always use android: and RelativeLayout when using Unity (it seems like that at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code, it works for me too. Maybe it is because your other way to run the code does not support constraintLayout, you can try RelativeLayout instead and see if it'll work.

Comment: Thank you, you pushed me in the correct direction. I will edit my question and explain a little more about this. Cause it wasn't just RelativeLayout I had to change, but thanks to previous errors I figured I had to replace app: with android: which in this case is invalid so I had to use android:layout_alignParentEnd="true".